# How to get type and value information from a template

Tags: c++, templates

Currently I have a template class that looks like this:

```
template<typename T, T value>
struct MyStruct{
   /* Stuff */
};
```

To instantiate it currently I do something like this:

```
typedef MyStruct<int, 123> struct_def;
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
typedef typename MagicTemplate<123>::type struct_def;
```

Which would resolve to `MyStruct<int,123>`....

So my question is how can I get both type and value information from a template argument?

**Edit**:

It would also be nice if the solution could be used with pointers, member pointers, function pointers, etc...

For example:

```
struct OtherStruct{
  int memberA;
  long memberB;
  void foo(void);
};
static OtherStruct instance;


//Expands to MyStruct<memberA OtherStruct::*, &OtherStruct::memberA>
typedef typename MagicTemplate<&OtherStruct::memberA>::type struct_defA;
//Expands to MyStruct<OtherStruct*,&instance>
typedef typename MagicTemplate<&instance>::type struct_defB;
//Expands to MyStruct<void (OtherStruct::*)(void),&OtherStruct::foo>
typedef typename MagicTemplate<&OtherStruct::foo>::Type struct_defC;
```

Comment: Only in [C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html).

Comment: @Oktalist Ah....that makes sense....too bad I can't use that yet

Comment: I guess macro (dark) magic it is then....since this is not really possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for C++17.

Or you punt; take a type `T`, and that `T` is expected to be compatible with an `std::integral_constant`.  This kicks the can one step further down the road; but shortcuts to make particular kinds of `integral_constant`s are cleaner than ones making some bespoke template instance.

For example, I can make `123_k` be of type `std::integral_constant<int,123>`.  Do `MyStruct<decltype(123_k)>`.

As  a bonus, your `MyStruct` now matches `template<class...>` which makes certain metaprogramming easier.

Comment: This is viable but somewhat clumsy because of the fact that you have to define an `operator""_k` for every single type you are interested in.....which is definitely an improvement, but I am going to have to deal with many many types here

Comment: @darth what types are you dealing with?  I mean, `size_t` for sizes, `ptrdiff_t` for differences, and `bool` for true/false usually solves my problems...

Comment: Also this does not work for pointer types.....(unless I know the address of the thing being pointed to)

Comment: Pointers to types....Pointers to members......Pointers to member functions.....Pointers to functions......integral types

Comment: But I might end up doing something like this for the integral types

Comment: Note that `std::integral_constant` works with those as well. (`""_` operators do not.)